# Spherical rigid body will never stop rolling regardless of drag

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

My problem is that I have a rigid body with a spherical collider and once it starts moving (rolling) it never stops.

I have read other answers here which state that changing the drag (angular and normal) is the answer to this problem but I must be doing something wrong somewhere else. I have been experimenting with this for hours and cant find a solution.

I have moved the drag to a million, still moves but very very slowly. I have moved the angular drag to a million with similar results. I have set the sleepThreshold to a high number. This didnt seem to do anything. I tried changing the friction on the terrain.

I placed the ball on a flat, horizontal plane for all of these tests and applied an impulse to start it moving. It has never come to a stop yet.

There are times when it reaches a certain velocity and then stutters like it is about to stop and then it starts moving at a constant velocity forever, I think I can visibly observe the shift from deceleration to constant velocity. It doesnt make any sense to me at all.

It is my assumption that the ball should stop eventually and that unity, being so advanced, would handle this easily but its possible that I'm missing something due to being so new.

Comment: Check if velocity magnitude <0.1f then make it 0.have you tried something like that

Comment: @burakKarasoy is rite. Make it zero manually at your minimum velocity.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm sure that would work. I guess I'm more interested in why I have to do this myself?  Seems like the whole idea of unity is to remove the burden of such things so I was wondering if I was missing something.  But if that's the only way, that's fine.